# what is the value of resultset ,if query does not return any record?

Tags: java

```
public ResultObject takePrefixGroupId(ArrayList prefixGroupName) 
{
 debugLog(MODULE_NAME, "Inside the takePrefixGroupId() of LCRConfigurationSessionBean");
 ResultObject resultObject = new ResultObject(LCRResponseCode.LCR_CONFIGURE_SEARCH_ERROR_EJB, null);

 String strSelectQuery = null;
 String strMessage=null;
 ResultSet resSet = null;
 Collection colInValideRecord =new ArrayList();
 Collection colErrorMessage=new ArrayList();
 Collection colValidRecord = new ArrayList();
 Collection colDataValidation=null;
 try{
  for(int i=0;i<prefixGroupName.size();i++)
  {
   strSelectQuery = "select DESTINATIONGROUPID from TBLMDESTINATIONGROUP where NAME='"+prefixGroupName.get(i)+"'";
   debugLog(MODULE_NAME, "Query::::::"+strSelectQuery);   
   resultObject = execute(strSelectQuery);
   if(resultObject.getResponseCode() == LCRResponseCode.SUCCESS_RESPONSE_CODE)
   {
    resSet = (ResultSet)resultObject.getResponseObject();
    debugLog(MODULE_NAME, "resSet::::::"+resSet);
    if(resSet != null)
    {
     while(resSet.next())
     {
      colValidRecord.add(resSet.getString("DESTINATIONGROUPID"));
     }
    }
    else
    {
     strMessage=LCRResponseCode.errorCodeToMessage(LCRResponseCode.PREFIX_GROUP_DOES_NOT_EXIST_ERROR);
     debugLog(MODULE_NAME,"MESSAGE::: "+strMessage);
     colErrorMessage.add(strMessage);
     colInValideRecord.add(prefixGroupName);
     debugLog(MODULE_NAME,"No Prefix Group is found."); 
    }
    colDataValidation=new ArrayList();
    colDataValidation.add(colValidRecord);
    colDataValidation.add(colInValideRecord);
    colDataValidation.add(colErrorMessage);
    resultObject.setResponseObject(colDataValidation);      
    resultObject.setResponseCode(LCRResponseCode.SUCCESS_RESPONSE_CODE);

   }
   else
   {
    debugLog(MODULE_NAME, "Unable to execute search query for in searchDestination() of LCRConfigurationSessionBean.");
    resultObject.setResponseCode(LCRResponseCode.LCR_CONFIGURE_SEARCH_ERROR_EJB);
   }
  }

 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  e.printStackTrace();
  errorLog(MODULE_NAME, "exception in searchDestination() of LCRConfigurationSessionBean");
  resultObject.setResponseCode(LCRResponseCode.LCR_CONFIGURE_SEARCH_ERROR_EJB);
  resultObject.setException(e);
 }  
 return resultObject;
}
```

this is the code

Comment: a reformat of your code is a must if you want answers.  for formatting help, go to http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Vanita: you have asked 13 questions and accepted 0 answers. People don't want to help you if you don't accept answers.

Answer (score 6):

According to [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29), `Statement.executeQuery()` never returns `null`.  So the answer is a `ResultSet` with no rows.

You can tell that the ResultSet is empty if `next()` returns `false` the first time you call it.

You may also be able to tell by calling the *optional* `isAfterLast()` method.  If it is supported, this method will give you an answer without advancing the cursor as a side-effect.

---

I've no idea what the answer would be for your code, since you are calling an `execute` method whose implementation you have not provided.

Comment: You can detect a `ResultSet` with no rows by calling `next()` on it, and it will return `false` even for the first row.

Answer (score 0):

> ResultSet executeQuery(String sql)
>                          throws SQLException Executes the given SQL
>   statement, which returns a single
>   ResultSet object.
>
> **Parameters:** sql - an SQL statement to be sent to the database, typically
>   a static SQL SELECT statement
>
> **Returns:** a ResultSet object that contains the data produced by the
>   given query; never null
>
> **Throws:** SQLException - if a database access error occurs, this
>   method is called on a closed Statement
>   or the given SQL statement produces
>   anything other than a single ResultSet
>   object

- [Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29)

Also you can do it like:

```
if(resSet.last().getRow() > 0)
{ 
 resSet.first();
 while(resSet.next())
 {
  colValidRecord.add(resSet.getString("DESTINATIONGROUPID"));
 }
}
else
{
 //...
```